# Glassfish Connection could not be allocated because: Identifier name '...' is too long

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, glassfish

So Im trying to run a Java EE project that was developed a couple years ago and Im getting this error:

```
Connection could not be allocated because: Identifier name 'c:\glassfish-3.0\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/databases/ejbtimer' is too long
```

Trying to run it on JDK7 and GlassFish 3

Tried searching for anything similar but to no avail

Any suggestions as to what is the cause/how to solve it?

EDIT:
stack trace (ext. link to not make post too long) http://pastebin.com/RzJS60aX

Comment: might help if you also post the stacktrace, to give an idea where the error occurs.

Comment: @Rop added stacktrace

Comment: from stacktrace, looks maybe more like mysql issue. suggest you add mysql tag. maybe you just dont have the db configured as expected by the source-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the documentation for the project had an error and the pool in GlassFish was set to the wrong Datasource Classname